# Trouble with ADO query from Excel VBA with dates

Tags: excel, vba, ado, adodb

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5zrN.png)

```
Dim strFileName As String
strFileName = "Acquired last 30 days.xlsx"

Dim lDays As Long
lDays = 2
Dim chkDate As Date
chkDate = Date - lDays


Dim cn As Object, cmd As Object, rs As Object

'---Connecting to the Data Source---
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1"";"
    .Open
End With

' Assemble paramaters and run
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CommandType = 1
    .CommandText = "SELECT [F1],[F3],[F4] FROM [Sheet 1$] WHERE F4>?"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pDate4", 7, 1, 30, chkDate)
    Set rs = .Execute
End With
If Not rs.EOF Then
    Do
        Debug.Print rs(0) & "-" & rs(1) & "-" & rs(2)
        rs.Movenext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End If
```

I've tried with and without parameters, with and without #, with and without BETWEEN, with and without using the same date format, with and without CDate() in the the where and select clauses (get an invalue Null error in the where clause - likely because of the blank lines at the top of the table). My basic test results return all the values or none of the values. Some examples:

All values including header:

"SELECT [F1],[F3],[F4] FROM [Sheet 1$] WHERE F4>#2018/01/05#"

"SELECT [F1],[F3],[F4] FROM [Sheet 1$] WHERE F4>#01/05/2018#"

Just header:

"SELECT [F1],[F3],[F4] FROM [Sheet 1$] WHERE F4>#05/01/2018#"

Nothing:

"SELECT [F1],[F3],[F4] FROM [Sheet 1$] WHERE F4 BETWEEN #01/01/2019# AND #01/01/2021#"

The data starts around row 15, and the date in the column 4 is stored as a date in Excel but formatted dd-mmm-yyyy. I'd like to avoid opening the file and reformatting it.

I'm at a loss. The only thing I can think of is to pull all the data and then evaluate it line by line in the recordset before writing, but I'd *REALLY* like to avoid that as well.

What am I doing wrong????

Comment: Curious; when data comes into the recordset, what do the dates look like? String? Number?

Comment: It comes in as a string formatted like so: '11-Feb-2021' I actually looked at the XML in the zipped xlsx file, and it's stored like this: "<c r="I14" s="2" t="n"><v>43243.0</v></c>" so I don't know why the query pulls the formatted version of the date.

Comment: Try formatting the date to ISO8601 with chkDate = Format(Date - lDays, "YYYY-MM-DD") and use an adVarChar parameter .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pDate4", 200, 1, 10, chkDate)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```vba
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandType = 1
        .CommandText = "SELECT [F1],[F3],[F4] FROM [Sheet1$]  WHERE F4 > ?"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pDate4", 5, 1, 30, CLng(chkDate)) '5=adDouble
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        Do
            Debug.Print rs(0) & "-" & rs(1) & "-" & Format(rs(2).Value, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            rs.Movenext
        Loop Until rs.EOF
    End If
```

Comment: That works when the file is opened, but not when the file is closed.

Oddly, both ways return a String in the value, but when it is open the string is the 5-digit date number (ie 43232) and when the file is closed, the string is the text as displayed in the screen shot ('23-May-2018').

Is there any way to convert the data in the WHERE clause before doing the comparison? I'm able to do so in the SELECT clause, but I get an Invalid use of Null when trying to do it in the WHERE clause.

What if I SELECT that column as a calculated date? How would I do that?

Comment: It works for me when the file is closed.  Does your data have headers?  You have your connection string set to "no headers", and if there is a header row that might be telling ADO that your fourth column is not all dates, so querying that column by date might give unpredictable results.

Comment: It does not have headers - the Example Data in the screen shot starts around row 15 where the first rows in column 1 contain bunch of properties of the pulled report. That said, it is all dates after the first 14ish Null rows. I'm using IMEX=1 because other columns, particularly the ID, are not as reliable and I wasn't sure how it would handle the blank rows.

Is there a way in the query to set the data type? It works to use CDate() in the SELECT, but it's still being evaluated as a string in the WHERE.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with ADO against a workbook, and dates are always tricky. My dates are formatted the same as your screenshot though, and I'm not seeing and issues.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I thought you had it the first time... until I went back to my source.

Answer (score 0):

It's not what I was looking for, but this was the only thing I could get to work.

I ended up writing a loop to put together the strings so that they match the results I was seeing from the recordset. (The column names are slightly different as I paired back the table for my original question, but you get the idea.)

```
Dim i As Long
lDays = lDays - 1
Dim strDate As String
For i = 0 To lDays
    strDate = CStr(Format(Date - i, "dd-mmm-yyyy"))
    strTemp = AHK_Append(strTemp, "F9='" & strDate & "' OR F15='" & strDate, "' OR ")
Next
strTemp = " WHERE F8='Acquired' AND (" & strTemp & "')"
```

I really wish there was a way to convert a value prior to evaluating it in the WHERE clause, but I'm moving on.